# A couple basic questions about AJAX housekeeping code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

Might be easiest to just see the comments in this code. As far as I know this is the housekeeping for all AJAX code, but I don't understand some parts of it!

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;
//Why are we calling/redefining the xmlHttp variable? 
// Why define it as createXmlHttpRequestObject() in the first place?

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //What exactly is an XMLHttpRequest?
    }else{
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

Probably stupid question: Is an xml object required for AJAX? I know its part of the acronym but I wasn't under the impression that server responses had to be in XML format.

I apologize if this is not the right way to put this question but I'm at a loss and am not sure where else I can go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> //Why are we calling/redefining the xmlHttp variable?
> ```

We're not.

> ```
> // Why define it as createXmlHttpRequestObject() in the first place?
> ```

We didn't.

Those are two different variables. One is local, the other is not. It's unfortunate that the author has chosen the same name for both, as this has confused you.

Ultimately, they end up holding the same resource, since the local one is returned from the function and becomes the value of the non-local one.

Consider the following similar example:

```
function foo() {
   var x = 0;
   return x;
}

var y = foo();
```

It's just like that except, in your code, the function definition came after the call, and the variables happened to have the same name. And your function did more interesting stuff with it. :)

---

> ```
> // What exactly is an XMLHttpRequest?
> ```

It's the internal name of a piece of technology inside your browser that makes AJAX happen. You should simply Google it for all the juicy details.

> Is an xml object required for AJAX? I know its part of the acronym but I wasn't under the impression that server responses had to be in XML format.

No. Historically XmlHttpRequest was designed for XML, hence the name, but it's by no means a requirement. Frankly I'd say it's pretty rare nowadays; people like JSON as an interchange format... though I'm sure, in some organisations, you still can't get away from the 1990s.

---

> As far as I know this is the housekeeping for all AJAX code

Actually, since you tagged this question [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you shouldn't be doing *any* of this. jQuery will internally perform all this sort of gubbins, allowing you to stick with [the handy `$.get`-family of functions](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). Again, all the details can be found online.